# Issue with suspend on Acer Aspire E5-571G-52FL

Tags: laptop, suspend, power-management

I have a Acer Aspire E5-571G-52FL and when try to suspend (when lid is closed for example) it not wake up after that. Only black screen and nothing.

3.16.0-33-generic

**UPDATE:**

Problem still exists in 15.04 (kernel version 3.19.0-16-generic). I found similar question [Black screen on laptop lid open after update to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622746/black-screen-on-laptop-lid-open-after-update-to-15-04), but i can't switch between TTYs.

I have one partion in dm-crypt and my home is in ecryptfs, also I have an cryptoswap. Could that be connected?

Comment: I have never been able to get my laptop to wake up from _hibernating_, only from _suspend_ (to RAM). You can change this behaviour in your power settings for "lid close action" or similar.

Comment: @TruthSerum question is about suspend. Not about hibernating.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but this workaround works only with Nvidia proprietary driver:

- Open nvidia settings.
- Go to PRIME profiles.
- Once there, you need to select the Intel card.
- Log out and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

Today I found a solution to a similar issue for my Acer Aspire E5-771G with Ubuntu 18.04. I run a stock 4.15.0-38-generic kernel.

Here is what I did to fix the issue:

- Installed proprietary Nvidia driver ver. 390 from Software & Updates
- Added the following two boot kernel parameters:

  `rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1 acpi_osi=!`

More about kernel parameters here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

I found this solution on Arch Linux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop/Acer