# Black screen on laptop lid open after update to 15.04

Tags: laptop, suspend, power-management

I suspend my laptop by closing the lid, but when I open it my screen stays black, when I should be prompted to enter my xscreensaver password.

The screen is "on" because I can switch TTY using `Ctrl+Alt+{1,2,3,...}` (and login if I want), but the xfce session running on the original TTY is just black with no mouse cursor visible.

**Before the screen goes black, I briefly see a command line login prompt, which suggests that my session has been logged out of the *command line* behind xfce. This could be a feature of the *server edition* of Ubuntu that I am using.**

If I switch TTY and kill my `xfce4-session` process, it causes the original TTY to go back to the gdm login prompt, and I can login again without the need to reboot my laptop. I am using this as a workaround for now. Also, it is not a problem with xscreensaver, because I have tried uninstalling it, and the problem remained.

This is a Dell Inspiron laptop with an integrated Intel graphics card.

During the upgrade process to 15.04, I was asked if I wanted to replace my grub configuration file, because the package maintainers version was different. I elected to keep my existing configuration. Could this have anything to do with it?

*Warning: Some of the instructions posted as answers can potentially break your installation.*

Comment: Are you really using GDM and xscreensaver? I ask because they are not the defaults in Xubuntu. You could try the defaults, lightdm and light-locker. I've had this issue myself in the past and it seems to go away with an update.

Comment: I had a black screen opening my lid on 14.10 today, even during boot, and it fixed itself when I plugged in my wireless mouse. Probably my laptop being weird though.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server 15.04 and have installed xfce 4.10 on it.

Comment: I refuse to award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

See if running the command

> dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

will help you any.  There are a couple other posts about people having similar issues when upgrading to 15.04.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not help.

Comment: Alright @TruthSerum , I'm not very experienced with the 15.04 release on laptops.  There are other posts, and they're not sure about what to do either, you can take a look at those.  Would you like the link?

Comment: Here you go, http://askubuntu.com/questions/613626/black-login-screen-ubuntu-15-04 might help {There are some answers, you can try those options!} @TruthSerum

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a problem with the greeter. I updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this problem. Basically, when we close the lid of the PC, it somehow reduces the brightness to 0 and you see black screen when opening lid again.

But if you increase brightness from function keys of your laptop, you will be able to see the login screen. That works for me smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem after updating ubuntu 15.04. Screen went dark after the ubuntu logo appears but was able to use TTY. I uninstalled the ubuntu desktop environment and installed genome and it started working. The codes i used are

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop unity && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

I didn't try, but believe it will work if you just reinstall the ubuntu desktop if you don't like gnome much.